Applying Different Roots of Ramanujan constant expression
I am not a mathematics student, but I have a deep interest in number theory.
Recently, I stumbled upon Ramanujan's constant $e^{\pi \sqrt{163}}$ which is remarkable for being extremely close to an integer.
This piqued my curiosity and led me to experiment with extending this concept to other roots.
Specifically, I applied various roots such as the square root, cube root, $4$th root, $5$th root, and so on, up to the $1000$th root, to the expression $e^{\pi\sqrt[n]{K}}$.
In this exploration, I found that some of these expressions produced values very close to integers, although none were as astonishingly close to an integer as Ramanujan's constant. Nonetheless, several values were intriguingly near integers.
Here are some of my findings:
For example

$e^{\pi\sqrt[363]{6780}} = 25.0000002432\ldots$
$e^{\pi\sqrt[368]{7656}} = 25.0000004809\ldots$
$e^{\pi\sqrt[371]{8235}} = 24.9999997914\ldots$
$e^{\pi\sqrt[376]{9299}} = 25.0000002337\ldots$

Was applying the different roots (not just the square roots) to the same expression which yields values close to Integers studied in Mathematics literature?  If yes, please point to some materials.

Unsurprisingly thats because 26569 is square of 163 ! As stated in my question , would like to know if there are any leads or work in this area. i.e. applying different roots to that exponential function.

In mathematics, the concept is called Almost integer. You can look at the Wikipedia Section here.
Furthermore, you can pay a visit to Wolfram Alpha too.
To suggest you some books, I have:
"Pi: A Source Book" by L. Berggren, J. Borwein, and P. Borwein. This book provides a comprehensive overview of the history and mathematics of $\pi$, including some discussions on almost integers.
"Irrational Numbers" by Ivan Niven. This book gives a good introduction to irrational numbers and includes examples and theorems related to almost integers.
Also, you can pay a visit to other sites, look at YouTube to have a detailed study on these numbers. A interesting term for you can be Schizophrenic number.

That's where i started and doing some experiments and posted the findings !  Thank you anyway :)
